# In set-theoretic forcing arguments, why do we need to prove facts about M[G] from the “perspective” of M?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, forcing

I’m trying to work through the forcing relation in set theory and the independence proof of GCH in particular. Although I feel like each step locally makes sense, I’m a bit confused about the necessity of some of the last steps which makes me think I’ve misunderstood something fundamental about the strategy. My understanding of the high-level argument is:

1. Take a countable transitive model of ZFC *M* and take a generic ultrafilter *G* over some suitable Poset in *M*
2. Show that the extended model *M[G]* is also a model of ZFC and that *M* can prove this
3. Even though *M* cannot “see” *G*, by use of Names and the forcing relation we can prove that there is some element *p* in *G* such that M proves that, for *any* generic ultrafilter *G’* containing *p*, the sentence we want to force is true in *M[G’]*.
4. So *M* proves that the sentence we want to force is in fact consistent with ZFC

Maybe this is a misunderstanding on my part, if so happy to be corrected here!

If that’s largely accurate though, I guess I’m confused why we need to prove so much about what *M* can prove about *M[G]* from its own “perspective”. Intuitively it seems enough that we can see “from the outside” that if *M* is a model of ZFC then so is *M[G]*, and so the Names/forcing relation steps seem confusing to me - I’m not seeing the necessity of proving that all of this is provable from within our original model.

Comment: The ability of $M$ to (limitedly) reason about $M[G]$ isn't something we want for its own sake; rather, it's crucial in technical arguments. Think, for example, about how we prove that if $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c. in $M$ then forcing over $M$ with $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't collapse cardinals (which is the key step in showing the consistency of $\neg\mathsf{CH}$).

Comment: Note that we really do need to "work inside $M$" here: after all, $M$ itself is usually taken to be countable, so without some sort of "$M$-based restriction" on how names can behave there's no obstacle to c.c.c. forcings collapsing cardinals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I assumed it was technically necessary and not just nice for its own sake but was missing why. I think this clears it up though. Just to check I’ve understood, would a way of rephrasing of what I missed be: although we can see from the “outside” that *M[G]* is a model containing *G*, we don’t have the guarantee that *M[G]* thinks $\aleph_0^M$ and $\aleph_2^M$ are different cardinalities (or at least that they differ by more than one level), and so we need to prove all this from within a model that definitely does respect these differences, I.e *M*

Comment: I think if you use the usual definition of $M[G]$, then the proof that $M[G]$ is a model of ZFC itself relies on the definability of forcing in $M$, because you have to show that all the $\mathbb{P}$-names you construct are sets in $M$.

Answer (score 4):

Belatedly turning my comments into an answer, the point is not that we care about definability-in-$M$ for its own sake (although it is super cool); rather, the definability lemma is pretty much the *only* way we can figure out how $M[G]$ behaves, and this includes even very basic questions like "Does $M[G]\models\mathsf{CH}$?" and so forth.

Consider for example the following pair of extremely useful slogans:

- "Forcing with a c.c.c. poset doesn't collapse cardinals."
- "Forcing with a countably closed poset doesn't add reals."

Each of these is absolutely crucial for the forcing-only proof of the independence of $\mathsf{CH}$, and can be intuitively justified without much effort. However, they're also critically under-nuanced as written. For simplicity let's look at the case where we're forcing over a c.t.m. $M$ - so generic filters actually exist unproblematically in reality, and the construction of the corresponding generic extensions is straightforward. Then *every* poset in $M$ is c.c.c. "in reality" and *no* (nontrivial) poset in $M$ is countably closed "in reality," **simply because** $M$ itself is countable. So the slogans above only make sense when interpreted *internally*: the right claims are "If $M$ thinks $\mathbb{P}$ is [c.c.c./countably closed] then every $\mathbb{P}$-generic extension of $M$ has the same [cardinals/reals] as $M$" respectively.

To drive this point home, let's think about how we would prove that if $M\models$ "$\mathbb{P}$ is countably closed" and $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$ then $\mathbb{R}^{M[G]}=\mathbb{R}^G$. Letting $\nu\in M^\mathbb{P}$ be a name for a real, we have that for every $p\in\mathbb{P}$ there is a sequence of strengthenings $p\ge q_0\ge q_1\ge...$ such that $q_i$ decides the $i$th bit of $\nu$. We want to apply countable closure to this sequence to get a common strengthening $r$ which will then decide all of $\nu$. However, **both** parts of this idea rely on $M$-definability of forcing! Firstly, since $\mathbb{P}$ can't possibly be *truly* countably closed (unless it's trivial), we can only find such an $r$ if $M$ can see the sequence $\overline{q}$, which in turn is only plausible if $M$ can define the forcing relation. Secondly, in order to go from "the condition $r$ decides all bits of $\nu$" to "Any generic $G\ni r$ has $\nu[G]\in M$" we need $M$ to be able to *see how* $r$ decides the bits of $\nu$.